# Group a XElement into a collection in Linq to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

This is an XML example:

```
<ProblemFactory Name="Diagnostic exam" Count="1">
    <Condition ObjectiveID="1" Type="1" CountRanges="2" Range1Decimals="0" Range1Min="3" Range1Max="10" Range2Decimals="0" Range2Min="6" Range2Max="10" />
    <Condition ObjectiveID="1" Type="1" CountRanges="2" Range1Decimals="0" Range1Min="6" Range1Max="10" Range2Decimals="0" Range2Min="6" Range2Max="10" />
</ProblemFactory>
```

And I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("ProblemFactory.xml");
        var problems = from pf in xdoc.Descendants("Condition")
                       select new
                       {
                           // ObjectiveID property
                           // Type property
                           // Ranges collection property
                       };
```

Create the ranges collection is my problem. How can I strutured my XML file or query to create the collection? The collection will contain: RangeDecimals, RangeMin, RangeMax.

I'm not sure, but I can Imagine to solve this problem I've gotta reestruct my Condition tuple:

```
<Condition ObjectiveID="1" Type="1" >
    <RangesCollection>
        <Range RangeDecimals="0" RangeMin="3" RangeMax="10" />
        <Range RangeDecimals="0" RangeMin="6" RangeMax="10" />
    </RangesCollection>
</Condition>
```

Comment: While it is possible to do what you're asking (Jimmy's answer), I strongly recommend changing the structure of your XML the way you mention.

Comment: You definitely should restructure your conditions to use what you have in the end.  Especially since the count of ranges could vary.  Though you really don't need `CountRanges` at all.

Comment: Ohh that's true. I can get it from the collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var problems = 
    from condition in xdoc.Descendants("Condition")
    select new {
        ObjectiveID = condition.Attribute("ObjectiveID").Value,
        Type = condition.Attribute("Type").Value,
        Ranges = Enumerable
            .Range(1, (int)condition.Attribute("CountRanges"))
            .Select(i => new {
                Min = (int)condition.Attribute("Range" + i + "Min"),
                Max = (int)condition.Attribute("Range" + i + "Max"),
                Decimals = (int)condition.Attribute("Range" + i + "Decimals"),
            }).ToArray()
    };
```

---

With the new format,

```
Ranges = condition.Descendants("Range")
    .Select(range => new {
        Min = (int)range.Attribute("RangeMin"),
        Max = (int)range.Attribute("RangeMax"),
        Decimals = (int)range.Attribute("RangeDecimals")
    })
    .ToArray()
```

Comment: Jimmy, I like your solution. Do you think you can help me to convert this code using the new structured I published?

Comment: With LINQ to XML queries, it's generally better to do an explicit cast to the type, rather than parsing it like that.  It's all built in.